# File upload from Ajax-Client to Python-Server with progress

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, file-upload, asyncfileupload

There is an excellent tutorial on how to build a Ajax/PHP file upload including a progress handler provided at http://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/File-Upload-Progress-Bar-Meter-Tutorial-Ajax-PHP.

The receiver of the transmission (file_upload_parser.php) is implemented in php. However I need to replicate its functionality in Python, which turned out to be significantly more complicated than doing a simple translation.

The main problem seems to be to recreate php's global $_FILES-array (http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.files.php) in Python, probably in the shape of a dictionary. I did not succeed using Pythons cgi.FieldStorage(), neither using the json module. Further, I had trouble keeping the connection established to listen for subsequent posts that might arrive (run_forever and the socket-approach suggested at [Connect JS client with Python server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184455/connect-js-client-with-python-server) turned out to not serve this purpose). There is plenty of documentation on how clients can write the file to the server using post. However I struggled to find information on how accomplish the read, that should occur on the receiving end of the transmission. At least not in a way that I could be implemented to yield the "file_upload_parser.php" functionality, which is key.